# Has SO considered adding facilities for removing or obfuscating sensitive data contained in posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, security

Many OPs cut and paste raw text such as code, config files and error messages into their posts. Many overlook passwords, directories, binary meta data and other sensitive information which can compromise security and privacy.

Of course, it is up to the OP to carefully check their posts before submission, but many in their haste or ignorance are unaware of it. Moreover, placing the security entirely on the individual is impractical, since a single breach can snowball into other ones.

It is difficult for a program to catch every piece of sensitive data, but has SO considered adding functionality to remove or obfuscate the common ones such as exif data and directory paths?

I am not advocating for blocking or altering posts, just for the detection of common ones and offering facilities to either remove or obfuscate them. Such a feature could add value by allowing cleaning up the posts.

Comment: To automatically detect sensitive info would be a humongous, expensive, complexity-adding undertaking that has nothing to do with SO's core mission and would come with loads of false positives - all for very little gain. There is an established workflow involving moderators for situations like this that has so far been perfectly sufficient.

Comment: considered it and implemented it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision

Comment: The only specific mechanism I’m aware of is diamond mods can redact edit histories. So the sensitive info can be edited out, and completely removed from the history of the post. That way, no one, outside diamond mods, can access the original sensitive content.

Comment: But what if the exif data is what the OP *wants* to show, because it's where their problem is?

Comment: Some information you refer to, such as exif data, might not be sensitive at all (yes, you might deduce my user name and computer name, but if my security is based on my user name being private, I ought to revise that, and you can crawl for computer names on a network). I don't have a clue why paths are sensitive also (I'm not really doing a good job of hiding my real name and identity on Stack Overflow too. You could even guess it from looking at my username!)

Comment: Exif data has GPS coordinates and can be mined.  Path names, especially coming from web servers can clue in a determined hacker.  These are easy ones to remove.  I am not talking about blocking posts, just make the poster aware and give them an easy way to remove the data.

Comment: EXIF data is not a concern. See my answer.

Comment: This is like Darwinism. Really, we can only take away so much responsibility from the individual. Someone will always find a creative way of shooting themselves, and the site can't detect everything.

Comment: @DanBron interesting titbit - in addition to it taking two mods to redact a revision (one to propose the change and another to sign it off) - after it's redacted mods can't see the original - we can see a redaction took place and who was involved in doing so, but we don't see anything further - that's a staff/dev thing.

Comment: *remove or obfuscate the common ones such as exif data and directories paths* - as Cerbrus has already said - exif isn't an issue as it's stripped - re: paths - sometimes, the problem is importing the wrong filename or importing from an incorrect path (or not understanding search order of file searches), and sometimes, questions are related to "how do I structure my project, here's what I've got so far..."

Comment: I am not advocating blocking, censorship or anything else.  I am only advocating simple facilities to detect and warn the user.  The user can either proceed with submission or they can edit their posts with facilities for removing or obfuscating pathnames.  For instance, VS output error messages contain paths that are easily parsable (?).

Comment: So, then someone can see my projects live in `C:/DEV/Company/Product`. Then what? What's problematic about that?

Comment: @ATL_DEV even if a system could be developed to reliably warn users - you do realise the majority of people that it'd be useful for are the kind of people that ignore warnings? For everyone else it'd be irritating. I'm failing to see any benefit to this whatsoever...

Comment: Paths are not generally that serious a security issue. The most common real-world problem with sensitive data on Stack Overflow is API keys. Building a system that detects real API keys (and can tell them apart from fake ones) in code would be a *huge* undertaking for very little benefit.

Comment: @JonClements  It all depends on how it is done.  Instead of warning the user, how about adding a feature that finds the paths in a post and allows you to replace or obfuscate them?  Ex.  Unknown var "$pass"  in "C:\equifax.com\www\login.php"  on line 1 column 22.  This is commonly done.  Also, you can also have a button that simply highlights questionable stuff like "pass" or even "equifax.com".

Comment: Again - the people that would get any benefit from it aren't going to pay any attention whatsoever.

Comment: Forget security for a second.  Don't you think adding the ability to easily change pathname to be of benefit?  I do it VERY often. It is a pain sometimes to replace them, especially if there are lots of them or they are very long.

Comment: @ATL_DEV it is indeed a pain, which is why they are a config parameter, (with reasonable defaults), in every app that I build.  Since they are all GUI apps, may users have a folder picker to locate their desired targets.  Devs using 1970's '$' interfaces can use a config file, or command-line parameters, or whatever.

Comment: My point is, why wast... spend effort on trying to shield incompetent OP's when the effort required could be spent on worth-while endeavours, (the new-user template maybe, or mentoring, or ditch-digging).

Comment: OK.  I understand,  SO doesn't want suggestions.  I will keep them to myself.  It is one thing to flag it down because it's  a bad idea, it's enitrely another to close because it's a duplicate when it was about adding convenience features.  Sometimes I wonder if Quora is sabotaging SO to gain marketshare.  If they are, it is certainly working.

Comment: @ATL_DEV SO 'doesn't want suggestions' no, not at all,  it puts them to the vote.  At -16, this one of yours lost.  You are aware that 'ordinary users' voted down this post, not just SO staff?

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out, moderators [currently have the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274#274274) to manually redact portions of a post to remove sensitive information. It requires two moderators to turn the key, because such redactions are permanent and will hide content from even moderators.

We regularly receive flags about sensitive material being posted (I just handled one right now), and paths and EXIF data are some of the least frequently noted items. Far more dangerous personal information is posted on a regular basis, including live server passwords, access keys, credit card numbers, home addresses, social security numbers, financial records, and the occasional dump of medical records. I've had to directly report three major HIPAA violations in the last year or so, due to incompetent developers posting actual medical records as sample data.

My point is that each of these privacy breaches was distinct, and I don't see a great way to identify them as they're being posted. The community is still our best guide to pick out and flag these violations. For many people, having a path to their code in their example isn't considered a breach of privacy, and others have pointed out the stripping of EXIF data. I don't think a good automated system could be assembled without a lot of training and testing.

Comment: Yikes... the most vulnerable part of technical systems remains the human part, it seems.

Comment: @TylerH - Let's just say that I have a little less confidence in the security of my information than before I was an SO moderator. Seeing someone go from asking "how can I get a database programming job without knowing SQL" to asking how to parse a U.S. state's Medicare records (with dozens of such records attached) doesn't help you sleep at night.

Answer (score 6):

I'd advise against implementing an automated filter (or detection method) like that, for one simple reason:

The thing the filter is blocking might be the *exact reason* for the question.
No matter what kind of data you're looking for, be it paths, api keys, phone numbers or whatever, you will get false positives.

Regarding EXIF data: [imgur already removes EXIF data/metadata](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201746817-Post-privacy), so that's of no concern.

Comment: Blocking, obfuscating, censoring, removing, replacing... It all has the same problem: The path may be important to the question.

Comment: The exif data was just an example. I will clarify my post.