# Automatically remove API keys from questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

### Remove API keys automatically

Over the last few days, I have had multiple questions that have included their API keys in their code.

#### Perfect example:

Just today I edited a post that had **payment authentication keys**...

Obviously most people aren't going to do anything bad with them, but since they are available to anyone on the world wide web, I think they should be removed.

#### How to do it?

I have seen other websites that convert serial numbers, usernames, keys, ect... into `XXXXXX`.

**My questions:**

- **Should this be done?**
- **How would you tell API keys apart from other code or hashes?**
- **Should SO maybe give a warning when users are asking a question?**

Following questions suggested as related in comments are not covering topic in this feature request:

- [Has SO considered adding facilities for removing or obfuscating sensitive data contained in posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358192/)
- [Remove Sensitive Information From Questions - IP Addresses](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/)
- [Guide on how to handle sensitive information in posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299688/)

Comment: Related: [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258066/11682469)

Comment: Did not see this, do you think that is good enough, or should they be removed automatically?

Comment: @rene that doesn't seem to be a duplicate of a feature request to do so automatically

Comment: duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358192/has-so-considered-adding-facilities-for-removing-or-obfuscating-sensitive-data-c or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/remove-sensitive-information-from-questions-ip-addresses and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299688/guide-on-how-to-handle-sensitive-information-in-posts

Comment: There are probably some API keys formatted in a way that could be reliably identified. Most are probably indistinguishable from other hashes/encoded data, though.

Comment: @rene Those do not answer my question.

Comment: @rene especially not "Should SO maybe give a warning when users are asking a question?"

Comment: @SethB Please clarify why "considered adding facilities for removing or obfuscating sensitive data" feature-request is completely different from this feature request that asks for removing sensitive data (API keys) from the posts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Should this be done?

No.

> How would you tell API keys apart from other code or hashes?

Exactly. How would you do that? if you get it wrong (and I'm pretty confident SE get things [wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944)) you'll be removing crucial info, rendering a valid question useless / unintelligible .

> Should SO maybe give a warning when users are asking a question?

We already give plenty of info, warnings, guidance that is happily ignored or [confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405232/578411). Let's not add more bells and whistles for cases that need manual human intervention anyway. Because secrets should not come near a public website. That is something we can't fix. Let's not pretend we can.

Comment: "and I'm pretty confident SE get things wrong" xD

Comment: I honestly don't know how some of these posters have made it as far as they have on their coding...  It's like "I need help with my email server using JS to send people invoices." and their code has something like `var email = invoices@company.com; var password = "My Very Secret Password";` SMH

Comment: With a bit of luck they pushed it on their public github repo as well ...

Comment: As for the email, that might get caught by the [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) as spam but only after it is posted. And once posted its indexed by Google.

Comment: The other day someone posted this: "I want to code web browser with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and do it with no external libraries and no errors. I already tried searching online and couldn't find anything."